# How do I build a string from individual characters over BLE HC-08?

Tags: arduino-uno

I am testing a BLE module (HC-08), which looks like a UART to the Arduino Uno.
This should be simple, but I have spent hours trying to build a string or char array from the response from commands sent over the software serial port.

first, here's the code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

int data = 0;
SoftwareSerial Blue(10, 11); // RX, TX

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Blue.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("BLE_Test started");
}

void loop() {
  Blue.write("AT+VERSION?");
  if (Blue.available()) {
    data = Blue.read();
    Serial.write(data);
  }
  delay(50);
}
```

And here's the output:

```
BLE_Test started
OK:SH-V1.251
OK:SH-V1.251
OK:SH-V1.251
OK:SH-V1.251
```

Each line ends with a CR-LF (13,10), so it looks fine on the screen.

So, here's my problem.
**How can I build a string or char array out of the bytes coming from the BLE module?**  My goal is to make a function that simply sends a command string to the BLE module and return a string from the function.  (Similar to Serial.readstring(), but SoftwareSerial has no readstring() property).

Like I said, it should be straightforward, but I am getting nowhere.  Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

it is `readString` with capital S and it is implemented in `Stream` which is a common base class for `Serial` implementations and `SoftwareSerial` and many other classes like LCD, EthernetClient, WiFiClient, ...

Answer (score 0):

Doh! [image: Doh!]

That works, here's my working code:

```
//Send the command to the BLE module, returns with response in global inData
void getBlue(char* blueCmd) {
  inData = "";
  Blue.write(blueCmd);
  delay(15);
  while (Blue.available() > 0)
  {
    inData = Blue.readString();
  }
}
```